# Evaluating the indefinite integral $\int\frac{(4-3x)dx}{5x^2+6x+18}$?

Tags: calculus

I have tried a variety of substitutions, including $u = 5x^2 + 6x + 18$, but I cant reduce the expression into something manageable. Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\int\frac{4-3x}{5x^2+6x+18}\,dx = \int \frac{29-3(5x+3)  }{(5x+3)^2+9^2}\,dx. $$

Answer (score 0):

We could try to force the numerator to be in a form similar to the derivative of the denominator, namely $10x + 6$, so as to exploit the integrals of $\ln$ and $\arctan$:

$$\begin{align}\frac{4 - 3x}{5x^2 + 6x + 18} &= -\frac{1}{10}\left(\frac{30x - 40}{5x^2 + 6x + 18}\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{10}\left(3\cdot\frac{10x + 6}{5x^2 + 6x + 18} -\frac{58}{5x^2 + 6x + 18}\right)\\
&= -\frac{3}{10}\cdot\frac{10x + 6}{5x^2 + 6x + 18} + \frac{29}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{5x^2 + 6x + 18}\end{align}$$

for which the first term can be integrated using $\ln$ and the second can be integrated using $\arctan$ after completing the square for the denominator.

---

In general, this approach should work as long as the determinant of the quadratic denominator is negative, in which case it can be completed as the sum of a square and a positive constant, such that the denominator conforms with the derivative of the $\arctan$ function.